# Duplicate shallow-DOF questions....

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

Hmmm. I flagged this:

[How to choose a lens to get a shallow DOF effect?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9425/how-to-choose-a-lens-to-get-a-shallow-dof-effect)

asking it to be merged into this:

[Can I get a shallow DOF using a kit lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5971/can-i-get-a-shallow-dof-using-a-kit-lens)

Because apart from camera brand and models vs. babies, they really are the exact same question.

But instead, [5971](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5971/can-i-get-a-shallow-dof-using-a-kit-lens) got merged into [How can I get dramatic shallow DOF with a kit lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5493/help-with-getting-bokeh-effect), which is another question on the same topic, with the unfortunate problem that the accepted answer isn't necessarily the best one. And maybe even more problematic from a "future duplicates" point of view, question [5493](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5493/help-with-getting-bokeh-effect) confuses things by calling it a "bokeh effect", which isn't really quite right.

The question is really "Is it possible to get shallow DOF with the kit lens?" and I think that's specific enough that it warrants being separate from "What causes shallow DOF?" in general. And "how does bokeh relate to shallow DOF" is a whole 'nuther issue.

(And meanwhile [9425](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9425/how-to-choose-a-lens-to-get-a-shallow-dof-effect) is still open, but I assume that's not for long.)

Comment: I really think that "Can I get a shallow DOF using a kit lens" should be open and valid.  It's one of those questions that I answer at least once a month in meatspace for folks asking me about photography.

Comment: @ahockley — yes, that's what I'm trying to say, in case I wasn't clear enough. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I went ahead and edited  the previously-named "Help with getting a bokeh effect" into [How can I get dramatic shallow DOF with a kit lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5493/). So now I'm happy. Hope everyone else is too. :)